# Can I change the type of an object at runtime in C++

Tags: c++, object

I have 2 objects in my C++ program, both extending from the same parent class:
class A, and class B, both extending class base.

Is it possible create an object using class A, and then change it later in the program to class B?

Comment: In principle, that is not a good idea. Can you explain why you need it and how you intend to use it?

Comment: You can convert an object of `class A`to an object of `class B` if you write a conversion function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, no. You cannot safely cast from A to B or B to A. You can safely cast to the base class since A IS_A base class and B IS_A base class but A and not a B and vice versa. There is no portable or safe way to do this. Whilst your compiler might let you do it and whilst it might appear to work the result of casting between to unrelated classes in this manner is undefined.

Incidentally, there is no reason why you can't add a cast constructor to allow A to be constructed from B and vice versa. That would be perfectly safe. You would just use the members of A to initialise the members of B and vice versa. Any members that are not common you'd have to deal with, probably be assigning them default values.

Comment: Exactly:  just create a function for `class A` (or, if you like, an overloaded constructor ...) which accepts an instance of `class B` as its input and which populates the (`class A`) object using values taken from it.  This not only "works splendidly," but it *also* clearly documents that the program from time-to-time has need to do that.  You're not "transforming one class into another," but rather, "initializing an instance of an object of one class, based on (specific) values taken from an instance of one (specific) other class."  And, you're explicitly stating just how that is to be done.

Answer (score 2):

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base {};
struct A : public Base {int a;};
struct B : public Base {int b;};

int main()
{
  A *a = new A();
  a->a = 1;
  B *b = reinterpret_cast<B *>(a);
  std::cout << b->b << std::endl; 

  return 0;
}
```

This is extremely ugly though and won't work properly if `A` and `B` don't have the exact same memory layout. This works if you need `a` and `b` to be the same object. If you don't mind them being different objects and residing in different places in memory then you can just write a constructor in `B` that receives an object of type `A` or a conversion operator.

This sounds like a classic example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and there probably exists a much more elegant solution to your actual problem.

Comment: `b->b` is undefined behaviour... right? ["Performing a class member access that designates a non-static data member ... on a glvalue that does not actually designate an object of the appropriate type - such as one obtained through a reinterpret_cast - results in undefined behavior."](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast)

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, no you cannot do this...technically. You can in fact achieve this effect through convert constructors and virtual functions.

If you write a convert constructor from A to B and B to A:

```
A::A(B convertFrom); // Convert from B to A
B::B(A convertFrom); // Convert from A to B
```

And you make the essential parts of each class virtual:

```
class base
{
    virutal void baseClassFunction();
};
class A
{
    virtual void baseClassFunction()
    {
        // Do things for A
    }
};
Class B
{
    virtual void baseClassFunction()
    {
        // Do things for B
    }
}
```

Then you can simply make a pointer of type `base` which can hold a reference to either `A` or `B`.

Example bringing it all together;

```
int main()
{
    base *ptr = new A();
    bool needs_to_be_B;
    ...
    // Program logic
    ptr->baseClassFunction();
    ...
    if(needs_to_be_B)
    {
        base *tmp = new B(*ptr);
        delete ptr;
        ptr = tmp;
        delete tmp;
    }
    // ptr is now a B
    ptr->baseClassFunction();
}
```

If you are confused look up virtual functions and convert constructors.